# Bind dropdownlist to SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 20 textboxes and a dropdownlist on my form.

I am using `EditItemTemplate` and a `SqlDataSource` for editing and inserting data.

I replaced a dropdownlist with a textbox and things didn't work. With the textbox, the form was working fine.

Initially, I had:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="IDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EPMProjectUID") %>'/>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsManageProject" runat="server" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT [EPMProjectUID] from Table"
     UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Table] SET [EPMProjectUID] = @EPMProjectUID "
     InsertCommand="Insert into [Table] values(EPMProjectUID)"
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="EPMScheduleUID"  />
     </SelectParameters>
     <UpdateParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="EPMScheduleUID"  />
     </UpdateParameters>
     <InsertParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="EPMScheduleUID"  />
     <InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And the things were working,I use to get the data and update it and even store it.

But now, I want a dropdownlist here, so I added

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="UIDDropDownList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

In the cs file, I wrote

```
  DB db1 = new DB(Global.ConnStringName);
  db1.QueryText = @"SELECT UID, ProjectName FROM Table ";
  DataTable dt = db1.GetDataTable();
  DropDownList ddlUID = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("UIDDropDownList");

  if (ddlUID != null)
  {
      ddlUID.DataSource = dt;
      ddlUID.DataTextField = "ProjectName";
      ddlUID.DataValueField = "UID";
      ddlUID.DataBind();
  }
```

And this helps me to load the data, but if I try to insert/update anything, it stores as null.

Comment: Well, you don't seem to have a `SqlDataSource` for your second query here - you're using a straight ADO.NET call to get the `DataTable` and that's it. So if you want to **insert** anything - it's up to **you** to find out which rows of data have been inserted and then write the necessary SQL queries to store those into the database....

Comment: How do you bind the SqlDataSource with the dropdown ?

Comment: When are you exactly populating the DDL? This might have a influence.